# Conditionals slower than operators?

Tags: boolean-computation

I want to make my application faster. I tried to replace an `If` condition with operators.

The `If` condition is

```
list = Range[4000];
Table[If[list[[i]] == 4000, Print[1], Print[2]], 
{i, 4000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Output is

> {7.739443, Null}

Using operators:

```
Table[(list[[i]] == 4000 && (Print[1]; True) || Print[2]), {i, 
4000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Output is

> {3.194183, Null}

Both give the same output but the execution time using operators is faster than `If` condition. Can you tell me which one is useful that does not have future problems as well?

Comment: I didn't edit the last sentence of your question. Could you explain what you're asking?

Comment: I know Operator condition is faster than If condition but i don't know will is affect the originality of if condition when we need to use nested if condition. Note: I know need to use more operators when we use Nested If condition.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm assuming that the goal of your function isn't to print out 4000 numbers to the notebook, In that case you should provide a better example since almost all the time spent here is used by the print statements.

Comment: I want to show the time taken to print number as an example, you just delete the output except AbsoluteTime.

Comment: I understand that you just delete the output, but why are you timing how long it takes to print 4000 numbers? If you have any sort of real usage, where you need to show the user 4000 numerical values you would never print them one at a time to the notebook. It seems like a very odd example.

Comment: I was just wanted to show the difference between If condition and Operators using print function, I don't bother about printing values.

Comment: `Print` is a poor choice of function to achieve comparative timings in this context. Additionally, if you look at the output from your two timing examples you will see they are not identical. Perhaps you have an example more relevant to you actual problem ?

Answer (score 6):

Just to illustrate what the comments are getting at, consider these variations below.  First, the three `If` calculations are consistently faster than the corresponding operator versions.
Second, the time it takes to execute `Print` is highly variable (see below).  Finally, let me add that operators are limited in their possible values (for example, `Or` yields `True` or the last value).

All of these variations calculate the same list of `True` or `Null` values.

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10^6];
iflist = Table[
    If[list[[i]] == 4, True,], {i, Length@list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.889342, Null}
> ```

```
iflist2 = Table[If[i == 4, True,], {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.567959, Null}
> ```

```
iflist3 = If[# == 4, True,] & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.863577, Null}
> ```

```
oplist = Table[(list[[i]] == 4 || Null), {i, 
     Length@list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.963072, Null}
> ```

```
oplist2 = Table[(i == 4 || Null), {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.627932, Null}
> ```

```
oplist3 = # == 4 || Null & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.950945, Null}
> ```

Note the form `Table[.., {i, list}]` is fastest in both cases, showing that the speed of `If` versus operator is not the major factor here either.

---

Here are the results of a few runs of the original code with `Print`.
There is difference between the two calculations: the first makes a list of all `Null`, while in the second all but the last element is `True`.  I tested a variation in which they calculate the same result, but clearly that difference is unimportant.

```
oldlist = Range[4000];
Table[If[oldlist[[i]] == 4000, Print[1], Print[2]], {i, 4000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {23.495759, Null}
> {68.451701, Null}
> {22.523382, Null}
> ```

```
Table[(oldlist[[i]] == 4000 && (Print[1]; True) || Print[2]), {i, 4000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {8.112765, Null}
> {17.992601, Null}
> {81.830045, Null}
> ```

Compare with a version that calculates the same list as the previous example:

```
Table[If[oldlist[[i]] == 4000, Print[1]; True, Print[2]], {i, 
    4000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {9.473233, Null}
> {46.342906, Null}
> {21.116975, Null}
> ```