# Seeking faster method than using Table and If together

Tags: performance-tuning

See the example below. Is there any way to make this execute much faster and still get the same output ? I have read [Conditionals slower than operators?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24906/conditionals-slower-than-operators) but it didn't really help me as I can't seem to apply these methods to my problem. I have to execute about 100 of these operations in succession and each one can't take about a second to execute as running the algorithm would take way too long for the end user.

```
CurrentEquipID = 40

40

AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[If[HTimeModelSelection[CurrentEquipID][[i]] == 
    0, (1 - HOperatingEfficiency[CurrentEquipID][[i]])*
    HUtilizedTime[CurrentEquipID][[i]], 
   Flatten[ConstantArray[
      Select[EquipParams, #[[colEquipID]] == CurrentEquipID &][[;; , 
        colOperatingDelayTime]], 20]][[i]]], {i, 1, 20}]]

{1.851185, {744.6512332, 744.6512332, 746.713979, 744.6512332, 
  744.6512332, 744.6512332, 746.713979, 744.6512332, 744.6512332, 
  744.6512332, 746.713979, 744.6512332, 744.6512332, 744.6512332, 
  746.713979, 744.6512332, 744.6512332, 744.6512332, 746.713979, 
  744.6512332}}
```

Comment: I'm not going to try to work out exactly what your incomplete code is doing but `Select` inside a loop may be slow.  Consider creating a hash table for each value (or position) rather than finding it with `Select`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard its worse than that, that entire branch is redundant, and should be excised. See my answer.

Comment: Considering how common an issue this is, I'm voting to close in favor of a [comprehensive question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/52) that you should read.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to leave a comment, but without seeing the full code, I think it can be improved drastically.

At fault is that you are performing the *same* search every time through the loop. (`If` has the attribute `HoldRest`, so the branches are not executed unless they are used which means the search is re-executed every through.)  So, at a minimum move the `Select` statement outside of the loop.

```
 currentEP = Select[EquipParams, #[[colEquipID]] == CurrentEquipID &][[;; , 
    colOperatingDelayTime]];
```

Additionally, your use of `ConstantArray[..., 20][[i]]` is redundant, and should be eliminated in its entirety. Replace it with `currentEP`. Lastly, using `Table` to index a `List` is inelegant; there are [better ways](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/52). Consider this use of [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[
 If[ #1 == 0, (1 - #2) #3, Evaluate@Flatten[currentEP]]&,
 {
  HTimeModelSelection[CurrentEquipID],
  HOperatingEfficiency[CurrentEquipID],
  HUtilizedTime[CurrentEquipID]
 }
]
```

The nice thing about this construct is you do not need to know what iteration your on, simplifying your code. Also, if the lists change in size, you do not need to change the code. A caveat is that they must all be the same size, or `MapThread` will complain, loudly. But, there are other methods ...

Comment: I *think* that `Evaluate@Flatten@currentEP` should be a real number -- the OP extracts part `i` from the flattened list.  Probably `Select` returns just one element, but who knows.

Comment: @MichaelE2 you are likely right, but I was not assuming anything, particularly with `Flatten` used _after_ the OP extracts the info from the list. But, `Evaluate` could be removed, as I believe `Flatten` is very fast, and the list is very short.

Comment: Anyway, I posted alternatives, but I think your approach is easier to understand.  `Unitize`, `UnitStep`, etc. and vectorized arithmetic seems a bit harder to me.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about the data, it seems likely that it consists of numbers, and the the times and efficiencies are positive real numbers.  Further I have to guess that

```
Select[EquipParams, #[[colEquipID]] == CurrentEquipID &][[;; , colOperatingDelayTime]]
```

returns a list consisting of a single number; otherwise, I cannot see how one would get predictable results picking the `i`-th element in the flattened array.

Here is some made-up data, on which your function works (i.e. runs without error and returns a list of real numbers):

```
nEquip = 10000;
numEquipmentStats = 100;
  colEquipID = 1; (* index *)
  colOperatingDelayTime = 3;  (* random index *)
CurrentEquipID = 40;
HTimeModelSelection[CurrentEquipID] = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, nEquip];
HOperatingEfficiency[CurrentEquipID] = RandomReal[1, nEquip];
HUtilizedTime[CurrentEquipID] = RandomReal[1, nEquip];
EquipParams = Transpose @ Join[{Range[nEquip]}, RandomReal[1, {numEquipmentStats, nEquip}]];
```

Your function takes `0.136795` sec.  (Perhaps the slowness your function has to do with the functions `HTimeModelSelection`, `HOperatingEfficiency`, or `HUtilizedTime` -- your code calls them repeatedly on the same input -- something to avoid if your functions take an appreciable amount of time to evaluate.)

If the data in this calculation, except `HTimeModelSelection`, are positive numbers, then the following will be fast.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Unitize[HTimeModelSelection[CurrentEquipID]] (1. - 
       HOperatingEfficiency[CurrentEquipID]) HUtilizedTime[
      CurrentEquipID] /. 
    0 -> Select[EquipParams,
          #[[colEquipID]] == CurrentEquipID &, 1][[1, colOperatingDelayTime]];]
```

> ```
> {0.002531, Null}
> ```

If the data is not all positive numbers, then here is a variation that works:

```
Transpose[{
     N@Unitize[HTimeModelSelection[CurrentEquipID]],
     (1. - HOperatingEfficiency[CurrentEquipID]) HUtilizedTime[CurrentEquipID]
    }] /. 
   {{0., _} -> Select[EquipParams,
                      #[[colEquipID]] == CurrentEquipID &, 1][[1, colOperatingDelayTime]],
    {1., x_} :> x};   // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.006147, Null}
> ```

If that's not fast enough, then perhaps compiling will help:

```
cf = Compile[{{model, _Real, 1}, {eff, _Real, 1}, {time, _Real, 1}, {delay, _Real}},
   If[#[[1]] == 0., #[[2]], delay] & /@ Transpose[{model, (1. - eff) time}]];

cf[Unitize[HTimeModelSelection[CurrentEquipID]], 
   HOperatingEfficiency[CurrentEquipID],
   HUtilizedTime[CurrentEquipID],
   Select[EquipParams,
     #[[colEquipID]] == CurrentEquipID &, 1][[1, colOperatingDelayTime]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.001194, Null}
> ```

Comment: You've got the order wrong, the ith element of `ConstantArray[...]` is picked then it is flattened. So, consistent results can be acheived. Oh, and +1 for pointing out that the OPs functions may be at fault, also.

Comment: @rcollyer Aren't the `[[;;, colOperatingDelayTime]]` elements picked, `ConstantArray`ed, and flattened; and then the `i`-th element is picked?  Seems like we're getting who-knows-which delay time, unless there's just one or they're all the same.

Comment: You were right, I was reading the closing `]` of `If` as the closing `]` of `Flatten`. But, a _lot_ of duplication ...